# Extrema of $f(x,y)=e^{-x^2-2y}-e^{-2x^2-y}$ in $D=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 \ | \ x \ge 0, y \ge 0\}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, solution-verification

**Problem.** Find the extrema of $f(x,y)=e^{-x^2-2y}-e^{-2x^2-y}$ in $D=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 \ | \ x \ge 0, y \ge 0\}$.

I have completed the study of this problem, however I have some doubts about my work: can someone check if I have done it correctly? Since $f$ is differentiable in all $D$, there are no points where the gradient doesn't exist and so I must check for the points that satisfy
$$\nabla f(x,y)=(0,0)$$
$$\iff (-2xe^{-x^2-2y}+4xe^{-2x^2-y},-2e^{-x^2-2y}+e^{-2x^2-y})=(0,0)$$
I find that this is true if and only if $(x,y)=(0, \log 2)$, but since $(0,\log 2)$ is not an interior point of $D$ the equation has no solutions.

So eventually the points of extrema are on the boundary of $D$: I parametrized the boundary with $\gamma_1 :[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}^2$ and $\gamma_2:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined as $\gamma_1 (t)=(t,0)$ and $\gamma_2 (t)=(0,t)$ and studied $g(t)=f(\gamma_1 (t))$ and $h(t)=f(\gamma_2 (t))$.

I found that $g$ has maximum at $t=\sqrt{\log 2}$, hence the point $(\sqrt{\log 2},0)$ is a point of maximum for $f$; moreover, $h$ has minimum at $t=\log 2$ and so $(0, \log 2)$ is a point of minimum for $f$.

Questions:

i) Is it correct what I've said about the fact that I have to reject the point $(0, \log 2)$ because it is not an interior point when I study the zeros of the gradient? If this is correct, then it is only a coincidence that one of the point of extrema of $f$ is the same as one that solves the equation $\nabla f(x,y)=(0,0)$?

ii) I am not completely sure if $\partial D$ is actually the rays $(x,0)$ for $x \ge 0$ and $(0,y)$ for $y \ge 0$, because it is an unbounded set; sorry if this is a very basic question, but I study physics and we don't give too much attention on how to determine rigorously the boundary of a set. Is is correct? How could I prove this?

Comment: Why would $(0, \log(2))$ be an infeasible point?

Comment: @cvanaret: As far as I know, derivatives must be done in open sets in order to have the possibility to give an increment $h$ to the variable and not "go out" of the set where the function is defined; hence, boundary points must not be included in the study of the gradient.